# SCCM Queries for Microsoft Visio Standard or Professional

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012

I am after a query that will show me whether workstation have a professional or standard version of an office product like visio 2010.

I have the following which I have found on here, but can not tweak it to show that, not very good with queries in SCCM at the moment.

```sql
select SMS_R_System.Name, SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName
from SMS_R_System
inner join SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS on
SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
where SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName like "%Visio Standard%"
or SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName like "%Visio Professional%"
order by SMS_R_System.Name
```

Updated the query and got it working how I like now. Run this against all active computers and it will return what version they have Professional or Standard.

Comment: [Seen this](http://scug.be/sccm/2010/04/13/sccm-report-count-of-all-instances-of-software-registered-with-add-or-remove-programs-that-you-want-to-list/)?

Comment: No I didn't, so far I have got it showing all Visio installed applications - select SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName from  SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS on SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName like "%Visio%"

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```sql
select SMS_R_System.Name, SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName 
from  SMS_R_System 
inner join SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS 
   on SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID =   SMS_R_System.ResourceId 
where SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName like "%Visio Standard%" 
   or SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName like "%Visio Professional%" 
order by SMS_R_System.Name
```